# AWS EC2 Container program command line arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, playframework

I am trying to run a Play Framework application on AWS EC2 Containers. I am using [sbt-ecr](https://github.com/sbilinski/sbt-ecr) to build and upload the image.
Now I would like to pass different command line parameters to Play, for instance `-Dconfig=production.conf`.
Usually when I run it locally my command looks like this:

```
docker run -p 80:9000 myimage -Dconfig.resource=production.conf
```

The port settings can be configured separately in AWS. How can I set Play's command line parameter for AWS EC2 containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my problem was of a completely different nature and didn't have anything at all to do with the entrypoint or cmd arguments.
The task didn't start because the **loggroup which was configured for the container didn't exist**.

Here is how to pass parameters to an image on ECS just like on the command line or using the docker CMD instruction. Just put them in the "Command" field in the "Environment" section of the container configuration like so:

```
-Dconfig.resource=production.conf,-Dhttps.port=9443
```